# Latex - Customization of bulleted lists (Overleaf)

Tags: lists, labels

i'm working on an online Latex editor called Overleaf ,i was trying to customize my list by using a different label , but it's not working ,

```
\begin{itemize}[font=\color{magenta} \Large, label=\ding{43}]
\item first item ;
\item second item ;
\item third item.
\end{itemize}
```

i used the package pifont and the problem is the same..
[image: This is the result]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please define “not working”. If I load the necessary packages (`pifont`, `enumitem`, and `color`) it seems to work.

Comment: it worked after adding a messing package which is enumitem , thank you

Comment: And always post full (but minimal) examples that others can just copy and test as is. Here you seem to be assuming to be able to use `enumitem` syntax, but is probably not using a template that loads `enumitem`